What is the storage method for the Oracle NUMBER data type?
I think there is a misunderstanding in the following introduction to the NUMBER data type. Could you please explain: does “calculate the decimal exponent” refer to the decimal exponent, assuming it equals N, is it similar to 10eN? Then what is “the base-100 exponent”?
The document address is: Oracle Data Types Documentation
To calculate the decimal exponent, add 65 to the base-100 exponent and add another 128 
if the number is positive. If the number is negative, you do the same,
but subsequently the bits are inverted. For example, -5 has a base-100 exponent = 62 (0x3e).
The decimal exponent is thus (~0x3e) -128 - 65 = 0xc1 -128 -65 = 193 -128 -65 = 0.

According to the explanation, assuming it is a positive number, this base-100 exponent equals X, then it should be X + 65 + 128 = N, not 0xc1 - 128 - 65 = N. I believe this N should be 100eN. Is it a documentation error or a misunderstanding on my part?

The "decimal exponent" in Oracle is calculated by:
For positive numbers: Decimal exponent = base-100 exponent + 65 + 128
For negative numbers: Decimal exponent = (~base-100 exponent) - 128 - 65
The example given in the documentation is correct. No errors there. You just misunderstood it.

"assuming it is a positive number" - but then you are saying the example is wrong, which is explicitly for a negative number (-5), not a positive number.

The numbers are stored as N = P * V * 100^E where:

P is either +1 or -1 and is stored as 1 or 0, respectively, in the most-significant bit of the first byte of the NUMBER
V is the value and is stored in the 2nd (and beyond) bytes of the NUMBER
E is the base-100 exponent and is stored in the 7 least-significant bits of the first-byte of the NUMBER (with an offset of 65 and the bits inverted if negative).

So:



Value
Equivalent Sum
P(ositive)
V(alue component)
E(xponent)




1
+1 * 1 * 100^0
1
1
0


50
+1 * 50 * 100^0
1
50
0


700
+1 * 7 * 100^1
1
7
1


-0.02345
-1 * 2.345 * 100^-1
0
2.345
-1




To reverse the process and go from the byte value to the exponent:

If the first most-significant bit (MSB) of the first byte is not set then invert the bits of the first byte (XOR with 255).
Subtract 128 to remove the most significant bit.
Subtract 65.

For the documentation's example of a first byte of 0x3e or 62 then:

The most-significant bit is not set so the number is negative and the bits need inverting. 0x3e XOR 0xff = 0xc1 (62 XOR 255 = 193).
Subtract 128 then 193 - 128 = 65.
Subtract 65 then 65 - 65 = 0.

So when the first byte is 62 then the number is negative and the exponent is 0.

An SQL example:
WITH find_byte (value, dump_value, first_byte) AS (
  SELECT value,
         DUMP(value) AS dump_value,
         TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(DUMP(value), ': (\d+)', 1, 1, NULL, 1)) AS first_byte
  FROM   table_name
)
SELECT value,
       dump_value,
       first_byte,
       CASE
       WHEN BITAND(first_byte, 128) = 128
       THEN 'Y'
       ELSE 'N'
       END AS is_positive,
       CASE
       WHEN BITAND(first_byte, 128) = 128
       THEN first_byte
       ELSE BITXOR(first_byte, 255)
       END - 128 - 65 AS exponent,
       FLOOR(LOG(100, ABS(value))) AS expected_exponent
FROM   find_byte;

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (value NUMBER);

INSERT INTO table_name (value)
SELECT POWER(10, 5 * (LEVEL - 1) - 20)  FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10 UNION ALL
SELECT -POWER(10, 5 * (LEVEL - 1) - 20) FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 10

Then the output is:



VALUE
DUMP_VALUE
FIRST_BYTE
IS_POSITIVE
EXPONENT
EXPECTED_EXPONENT




.00000000000000000001
Typ=2 Len=2: 183,2
183
Y
-10
-10


.000000000000001
Typ=2 Len=2: 185,11
185
Y
-8
-8


.0000000001
Typ=2 Len=2: 188,2
188
Y
-5
-5


.00001
Typ=2 Len=2: 190,11
190
Y
-3
-3


1
Typ=2 Len=2: 193,2
193
Y
0
0


100000
Typ=2 Len=2: 195,11
195
Y
2
2


10000000000
Typ=2 Len=2: 198,2
198
Y
5
5


1000000000000000
Typ=2 Len=2: 200,11
200
Y
7
7


100000000000000000000
Typ=2 Len=2: 203,2
203
Y
10
10


10000000000000000000000000
Typ=2 Len=2: 205,11
205
Y
12
12


-.00000000000000000001
Typ=2 Len=3: 72,100,102
72
N
-10
-10


-.000000000000001
Typ=2 Len=3: 70,91,102
70
N
-8
-8


-.0000000001
Typ=2 Len=3: 67,100,102
67
N
-5
-5


-.00001
Typ=2 Len=3: 65,91,102
65
N
-3
-3


-1
Typ=2 Len=3: 62,100,102
62
N
0
0


-100000
Typ=2 Len=3: 60,91,102
60
N
2
2


-10000000000
Typ=2 Len=3: 57,100,102
57
N
5
5


-1000000000000000
Typ=2 Len=3: 55,91,102
55
N
7
7


-100000000000000000000
Typ=2 Len=3: 52,100,102
52
N
10
10


-10000000000000000000000000
Typ=2 Len=3: 50,91,102
50
N
12
12



fiddle
